# Visual Studio 2012 Express MVC 3 deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio, express

I have developed a a MVC 3 application in Visual Studio 2012 express and I'm trying to create a web deployment package following the documentation in this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(WebApplicationProjects.PackagePublishOverview);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0)&rd=true

I have a couple of issues.
1. I cannot select deploy check box in the configuration manager, it is greyed out
2. The zip file is not being created

Is this a limitation of the version of visual studio or am I going about deploying this type of project wrong. Due to the nature of the application the web deployment package is the best deployment option.